# Android how to connect two activity if the button onclick with conditions if

Tags: android, arrays, string, button

all

I have difficulty in linking the two activities by using two buttons. The first button serves to select the item in the array. The second function button to proceed to the next page if the text appears on the first button "string 1"

What should I add in my code

This code in array.xml for button3

```
<string-array name="myArray"> 
<item>string 1</item> 
<item>string 2</item> 
<item>string 3</item> 
<item>string 4</item> 
<item>string 5</item>
```

This code in beta.java

```
private String[] myString; 
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.next);
    Resources res = getResources();

    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray); 



    Button btn2;
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

            ((Button) v).setText(q);



        }

    });

    Button btn3;
    btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

}
}

What should I add in button4 to be able to go to the next page if the text in the button3 perform "String 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing use the final keyword before button **btn2** like

```
final Button btn2;
```

and use the following code at click of button btn 3

```
if(btn2.getText().toString().equals("string 1")){
      Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: its work, yeah. .  There were fewer errors. :D thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
      Button btn3= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
      btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent i=new Intent(presentactivity.this,nextactivity.class);
               startActivity(i);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in onclick of btn3

```
String s1=btn2.getText().toString();
if(s1=="String 1")
{
 Intent i=new Intent(presentactivity.this,nextactivity.class);
           startActivity(i);
}
```

declare Button btn2  before onCreate method.

Comment: it is a String as i showed in code.. :| because you told " if the text in the button3 perform "String 1"" you should go to next page.. what is perform "String 1" ?